# Breakpoints are ignored in VS-Code debugging C with gdb

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I try to debug my C-code but my breakpoints are ignored.
My system is Windows 10. VS-Code version is 1.38.

This is my launch.json entry:

```
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "C:/Users/NCH-Lap10/Desktop/aaa.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
    },
```

I would appreciate any hints.
Could I provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm sharing my config files, just add them under `.vscode` folder, and also name the files as given below.

### c_cpp_propreties.json

```
{
   "configurations":[
      {
         "name":"Win32",
         "includePath":[
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/trl"
         ],
         "defines":[
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
         ],
         "compilerPath":"C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
         "cStandard":"c11",
         "cppStandard":"c++17",
         "intelliSenseMode":"clang-x64"
      }
   ],
   "version":4
}
```

### launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Compile C File"
        }
    ]
}
```

### tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile C File",
            "command": "gcc",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceRoot}\\a.exe"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to work above configs, you need to have at least `launch.json` and `tasks.json`.

Comment: @kame Also you are using gdb for c code debugging that won't work you need to have gcc for c, and gdb for cpp.

Answer (score -1):

try to rebuild code

1. activate tabs with your code
2. press Ctrl+Shift + B
3. start debugging by pressing F5